# Assign cell background color to rgb from referenced cells and repeat for many or all rows

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to make the background colour of col D to the RGB codes taken from cells A,B,C
[example of rgb background loo]

This formula was provided to another query and does work for 1 row
Range("F1").Interior.Color = RGB(Range("C1"), Range("D1"), Range("E1"))

How do I make that repeat for many rows or all rows

I am very new to Visual Basic so if there is any assistance that would be much appreciated

Comment: Sounds like you need a loop?

Comment: Let's say you want to write a value into all cells of column A between row 1 and 10. Then you would use a loop like BigBen suggests. You would write a loop that starts at 1 and goes to 10. The iteration variable for your loop would be something like `currentRow`that is increased by 1 every iteration. Here is a concise tutorial on how to use loops: https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/loop.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this ?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If ActiveCell.Column > 3 Then Exit Sub
Set oFill = Range("D" & ActiveCell.Row)
Set Rng = Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row, Range("C" & ActiveCell.Row))

For Each cell In Rng
If IsEmpty(cell) = False And IsNumeric(cell) = True Then n = n + 1
If n = 1 Then x1 = cell.Value
If n = 2 Then x2 = cell.Value
If n = 3 Then x3 = cell.Value
Next cell

If n = 3 Then
oFill.Interior.Color = RGB(x1, x2, x3)
Else
oFill.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
End If

End Sub
```

The code is to be put in worksheet module.
The color filling will happen if all the three column (A B C) in the same row has value and the user select any cell within column A to C after he/she fills the three cells (A B C) in the same row.

[image]